# Jmeter result analysis (*.jtl) by using "R" language

Tags: jmeter

can we use "R" for jmeter result analysis, what will be the advantage and disadvantages ??

Anybody currently working on this ??

Comment: If you ever find the advantages of using R, please add your answer. I am also interested to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/hali/Performance-data-processing/blob/master/output/analyze.R). I had bookmarked that sometime last year thought of checking later, before I was looking into InfluxDB.

I send my results to InfluxDB (explained [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/)) which can give all the aggregate information like, min, max, avg, median, percentile etc / per given interval. It can be easily integrated with Grafana which will produce stunning charts with your data.

**Source**: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to store JMeter result in CSV format and not jtl

It's easiest to load and use the CSV file

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

No need to use "R", JMeter comes Out Of The Box with a very rich HTML report:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

JMeter can also send Out Of The Box live results to  different backends:

- Influx DB
- Graphite

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

You can then use this Grafana report :

- https://grafana.com/dashboards/335